Pine gets yellow needles and new shoots are twisted
What can I do about the shoots and needles? Is it some fungal infection?


After putting one needle under microscope it's full of this stuff.


Where is the tree growing?  what part of the world?

Poland. It's about 11 to 20 deg now but there was unusual event of very warm temperatures in April followed by -5 for 2 days. This killed my magnolias.

After digging on the internet with image search it turned out this looks like fungal infection with Lophodermium pinastri. I will try to use fungicides. Thank you all for your time and help!

After seeing the first two images it is visible that the reason of Pine becomes yellow needles and new shoots are twisted is the temperature, as the sudden down in temperature leads to plant stress.
In this vulnerable situation, plants also got attacked by pests as I can see in the third microscope image. Thus, the temperature falling and insect attack made the situation worse which led to yellow needles and twisted new shoots.
To get rid of the situation you should first use an Insecticides spray and spray it on pine then rinse it off with normal water after 3-4 hours.
Secondly, if the temperature will be in 10-20 deg then it's okay to just give proper watering but if the temperature is lower take some measures to cover the plant otherwise it will not grow and the situations become worse.

Covering a pine is not a good idea. And recommending an “insecticide” without any hint as to what the asker is dealing with? Also not good.
